# How to have select option pre-selected in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am passing some data to a modal window in my Ionic/Angular app, but I can not get the select option to be pre-selected based on the data.

In the parent of my modal, I use the `componentProps` to pass the data from my parent to the modal, like this:

```
async editImage(imageID) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: EditImagePage,
      componentProps: {
        data: this.imageMetaData
      }
    });
    await modal.present();

    const { data } = await modal.onWillDismiss();
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
```

My data that is passed in to the modal is structured like this:

```
this.data = {
  albums: ["39902"],
  user_id: "49"
}
```

This is some mock data that comes from my API:

```
{
    "albums": [{
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "27508",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Marvel Comics",
            "count": "123"
        }]
    }, {
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "27509",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Baseball",
            "count": "77"
        }]
    }, {
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "33670",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Basketball",
            "count": "4"
        }]
    }, {
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "39902",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Football",
            "count": "331"
        }]
    }, {
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "39968",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Hockey",
            "count": "1,552"
        }]
    }, {
        "album": [{
            "albumID": "40585",
            "userID": "49",
            "albumName": "Test Album Name",
            "count": "0"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In my modal, I call my API service to get the data like this:

```
this.api.getAlbums().subscribe(response => {
  this.albums = response['albums'];
});
```

In my template, I try and display the selected values like this:

```
<ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Album</ion-label>
      <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="data.albums">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of albums" [value]="item.album[0].albumID">{{item.album[0].albumName}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

When the page loads, the value for the drop down is not selected, however, if I click on the drop down, then the correct value is selected.

Is there a way to get the selected value from `this.data` to appear selected in the dropdown?

Bonus points for anyone who can also help remove those silly ellipses from the drop down's in Ionic.

Comment: are you sure you have provided the correct albums json? because `this.albums` is not not array and `*ngFor` only works with array.

Comment: @VivekJain - you are correct, I edited to clarify my approach and how `this.albums` is getting the array set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related with a race condition: maybe Ionic is rendering the select component before the request to fetch the `albums` data completes.

This is why if you set statically the `albums` variable it works the first time.

To avoid the problem, one thing you can do is define an `*ngIf` on the ion-select component that will be evaluated as true when the `albums` arrive:

```html
    <ion-item lines="full">
      <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Album</ion-label>
      <ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="data.albums" *ngIf="!!albums">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of albums" [value]="item.album[0].albumID">{{item.album[0].albumName}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Please, be aware that you need provide some fallback if there is some error when fetching `albums`. You can set the variable to an empty array in that case, for instance.

Also, this solution could potentially produce some kind of flicker effect if the request to fetch the `albums` is slow; if this happens, you will need to include some kind of spinner in your page.

Another option will be include in your `data.albums` variable at least the name of the album itself, instead of only the name. I want to say:

```js
data.albums = [{"albumID": "39902", "albumName": ""}, ...]
```

This will allow you to preload the album selector until the availability of the actual `albums` information.

Finally, you can try to force change detection when your `albums` data arrives:

```js
this.api.getAlbums().subscribe(response => {
  this.albums = response['albums'];
  this.cd.markForCheck();
});
```

Being `cd` an instance of `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: My apologies for my original post not being more clear. 

`data` is passed in from the parent of the modal. It represents the metadata for the image that is going to be edited. One of items that can be edited is which album the image belongs to. In `data` there is an albums array that may have one (or more) album IDs associated to it.

`albums` is retrieved from my API service, and returns an array of all of the users albums. The idea being that the `ion-select` would have initial value selected if any an album ID in `data.albums` matched any of the album IDs in `albums.album[0].albumID`.

Comment: @zeropsi there is no need for apologize. In any case, please, apologize me for not understand the explanation. It is ok. And how and when do you pass the information from your parent to the modal? Please, can you explain better this point?

Comment: Sure thing. I have edited the original post to include how I use the `componentProps` in my parent page to pass the data to my modal. In my modal, I am able to see that the data is set, if I use `console.log(this.data)` in my `ngOnInit` method. Strangely enough, if I set my `albums` statically, and remove the API service call, then the initial value in `ion-select` is set correctly.

Comment: @zeropsi I updated my answer with one possible solution for your problem. When you be able to, please, can you give it a try? And thank you for editing the original post: it was of great help in understanding the problem.

Comment: It certainly appeared to be a race condition in my code. I made a slight tweak to your code and changed my `ion-select` to `<ion-select multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="data.albums" *ngIf="albums.length > 0">` and everything is working as expected.

Comment: @zeropsi I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful. Please, in any case, review the behaviour of the app when, for instance, you do not receive any albums (i.e., you have an empty array). Is the select presented ok? If not, just initialize to ```null``` the ```albums``` variable - I suppose you are initializing it to an empty array, and test the ```*ngIf``` condition with ```!!albums``` (I will update the answer with it). This will allow you, for instance, to show the select even in case of errors - if you followed my advice and set the ```albums``` variable to an empty array in that case